# @use sass rule doesn't work in my webpack configuration

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server, sass-loader, webpack.config.js

I have this config: [My config to sass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlZyG.png) and when I run webserver I get this: [Error img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hq9w.png).Moreover, without this mcolor variable I anyway don't get any styles from _variables.scss. Can I use @use rule with webpack? Am I doing anything wrong? By the way @import works well!
File structure and file contents: [File content_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0AJeP.png) and [File content_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KI87e.png)

I was trying realod server and any more. Nothing works.

Comment: You should do this. @use '../ variables' as *. Then you dont need the variables.$mcolor.